# Goes to the start of the command in screen

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

After running a command that spits out a lot of output in screen. I drop to Copy mode and try to find where the command start. This becomes very very challenging when there are lots of lots of similar text to sift through. Is there a way for me to quickly scroll to where my command starts?

Comment: I use a colored prompt for this reason :-)

Answer (score 2):

pipe to the 'less' command like

cat foo |less

that means less is running and you will have to leave less with the 'q' key to get back to bash
less allows you to search or move quickly to the top.

Comment: 1 more thing.  this pipes stdout to less.  not stderr.  so error messages get lost, more or less

Comment: To merge stderr into stdout, do `cat foo 2>&1 | less`.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect(>) the output from command to a file  and then get what you want. i don't have any idea to scroll where the command starts precisely.
by the way, different terminals have different features and not all terminals support the feature which you want.